# Why would changing the margin of a header tag move its parent and grandparent elements?

Tags: html, css

I have an `h1` tag that, when I change its `margin-top` property, it moves the parent and grandparent elements as well.  Can anyone explain why this would occur and how to fix it?

If you notice, when the `h1` margin is set to `0 auto` the two sections have the correct gutters between them.

[Pen1](http://codepen.io/RobbyT15/pen/evoqpV)

```
<section></section>
<section>
    <div class="notice">
        <h1>Our website is currently undergoing construction, please feel free to contact us on social media.</h1>
    </div>
</section>

section{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
}

section:nth-of-type(2){
    background-color: blue;
}

.notice{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 10vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.notice h1{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

However, once I set the `h1` element to have a margin, doing so moves the parent div and grandparent section elements.

[Pen2](http://codepen.io/RobbyT15/pen/MpRNyO)

```
<section></section>
<section>
    <div class="notice">
        <h1>Our website is currently undergoing construction, please feel free to contact us on social media.</h1>
    </div>
</section>

section{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
}

section:nth-of-type(2){
    background-color: blue;
}

.notice{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 10vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.notice h1{
    margin: 50px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called "margin collapse". The margin is collapsing outside of the parent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, block_formatting_context created or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. **The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.**

One way to fix it would be to add `overflow: hidden` to the parent

```css
section{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: red;
 overflow: hidden;
}

section:nth-of-type(2){
 background-color: blue;
}

.notice{
 width: 100vw;
 height: 10vh;
 text-align: center;
}

.notice h1{
 margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section>
 <div class="notice">
  <h1>Our website is currently undergoing construction, please feel free to contact us on social media.</h1>
 </div>
</section>
```

Or you can use `padding` instead of `margin`

```css
section{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: red;
}

section:nth-of-type(2){
 background-color: blue;
}

.notice{
 width: 100vw;
 height: 10vh;
 text-align: center;
}

.notice h1{
 margin: auto;
 padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section>
 <div class="notice">
  <h1>Our website is currently undergoing construction, please feel free to contact us on social media.</h1>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: So basically, I need to set the margins on the parent and grandparent elements?

Comment: @Robert a number of ways you can fix it. You can use a `padding-top` on the section or on the heading, instead of margin on the heading. Or you can add `overflow: hidden` to the section. There are other ways of addressing it, too, if neither of those work for you.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the info, the link, and the solution.

Comment: @Robert you're welcome. Sorry I missed the part about "how to fix it" in your question. Updated my answer with a solution.